# Unable to connect to SVN server from another server

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, svn

Working on Ubuntu Linux 22.04.2
The SVN server is working fine, and I can access it locally to do all I need.
The problem is when I try to access it from another server.
Here is what I get when I try telnet:

```
telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3690
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

Netstat give me:

```
sudo netstat -tuln
```

One of the line is

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3690            0.0.0.0:*
```

There is NO firewall that I know of enabled. From the hosting control panel firewall is turned off.
On the server, UFW is disabled.

What else could be stopping the connection, is there anything thing I should set up?
any insight will be very appreciated.

Comment: *What else could be stopping the connection* - perhaps because there is `No route to host` - don't know your networking setup, so, can't help - is `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` something like `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x` or `100.64.x.x`?

Comment: Running a tcpdump on the server to see what it is seeing and sending may be helpful to you - maybe run something like "sudo tcpdump -n -i any port 3690"

Comment: How do I add a route? I am sorry I am not familiar with that concept, I usually install LAMP and all is setup, but it seems with SVN I need to do something else which I don't know how.

Comment: when I run sudo tcpdump -n -i any port 3690 this is what I get: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa is my computer's local IP, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my server IP.

08:58:39.818328 enp1s0 In  IP aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa.34709 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.3690: Flags [S], seq 2782063315, win 65535, options [mss 1400,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3285140538 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0

Answer (score 0):

when I run sudo tcpdump -n -i any port 3690 this is what I get: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa is my computer local IP, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my server IP

```
08:58:39.818328 enp1s0 In  IP aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa.34709 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.3690: Flags [S], seq 2782063315, win 65535, options [mss 1400,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3285140538 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

How do I create a route?